# How do I connet to exchange web service using node js/Oauth

Tags: node.js, oauth, exchangewebservices

After ews basic authentication disabled I need to Implement oauth for ems using nodejs

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't describe a specific problem, I'll just leave these references to get you started.

https://learn.microsoft.com/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-authenticate-an-ews-application-by-using-oauth

https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-nodejs-webapp